# Recent values in CharField

Tags: django, forms, select

I have some model

```
class Mod(Model):      
    f = CharField(max_length=10)
```

And some form:

```
class ModForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mod
        fields = ('f',)
```

When I display form to user I want to suggest some dropdown with Mod.objects.all() values of 'f'. How to do this in simplest way? I tried specify widgets = {'f': Select}, but it is not editable. I also can use selectize.js to make it selectable with preloading ajax values, but seems like this is too long way.

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#field-choices

Comment: I already tried this, as I see  when I pass some tuple to choises option in CharField it also creates  not editable <select>

Comment: I had the same needs and used https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models.py

```
class Mod(models.Model):
  CHOICE_1 = 'CHOICE 1'
  CHOICE_2 = 'CHOICE 2'
  FIELD_CHOICES = (
    (CHOICE_1, 'The real charfield value'),
    (CHOICE_2, 'another charfield value')
  )
  f = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    choices=FIELD_CHOICES,
    default=CHOICE_1
  )
```

forms.py

```
class ModForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mod
        fields = ('f',)
```

end of views.py

```
return render(request, 'template.html', context={'mod_form': mod_form})
```

template.html

```
{{mod_form.as_p}}
```

This is extracted from working code. Hopefully the obfuscating my specific app out did not make it unclear.

Comment: Tried it, but it displayed like select tag with two options, it is not possible to edit it =(

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is a simple and nice solution. Thanks to Bilou06.
So, first of all we need to pass list of values, we can do it in view:

```
args['f_vals'] = Mod.objects.all().values_list("f", flat=True).distinct()[:10]
```

here we get all flat list of values and perform distinct to filter only uniq values. Then we limit values to 10. Additional benefit here is that we can perform more complex querysets with additional filtering and so on. For example if you have some field you can order it to be real "recent". (You can edit this answer to provide some example).

Next we pass our args into template, and there create autocompleate:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_f").autocomplete({
            source: [{% for v in f_vals %}
                       "{{v}}",
                     {% endfor %}
                    ],
            minLength: 0,
        }).on("focus", function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

On focus event here displays list of recent values immidiately on focus. Also values will be filtered when you typing.
Note that you should include jquery-ui:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
```